# Unable to run functional tests on server. [geb spock]

Tags: grails, testing, spock, automated-tests

Hi I am running my functional tests using geb. 
I am able to run tests on my local computer correctly. but as I deploy my application to server. the build for functional tests fails.

Here is my console output

```
|Running 10 spock tests... 1 of 10
Failure:  |
sign in with voucher
 |
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script14007213321291157436758$_run_closure1@77068fce'
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:346)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:335)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
    at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:377)
    at geb.Page.to(Page.groovy:171)
    at geb.Browser.via(Browser.groovy:454)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:413)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:391)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:51)
    at VoucherSpec.sign in with voucher(VoucherSpec.groovy:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/local/bin/firefox) on port 7056; process output follows: 
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified
```

Can anyone guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful? If so please accept it so that other people can see if it helped (and I can get some points...). Cheers!

Comment: That is great effort from you to help me. I am unable to run tests through HtmlUnitDriver too. Any way thank you for your time to help me .

Comment: No problem. To help you with the HTMLUnitDriver it would be great if you could open a new question and mark this as answered. This helps to keep things separate, and means you can post error messages/code snippets so it's easier to help. If you add the URL of the new question into a comment here I'll help out ASAP. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The server you're running the tests on is 'headless' so doesn't have a display to start Firefox on to run the tests. You've got a couple of options:

1. Switch from Firefox to a headless browser such as [HTMLUnit](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver).
2. Configure a virtual display on the server.
3. Use a remote browser service such as [SauceLabs](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/sauce-labs.html).

If you need to test directly on Firefox then HTMLUnit isn't an option for you.

Using a remote browser service such as SauceLabs or BrowserStack has a couple of advantages, for example they record a video of the session and take screenshots, but we found the overhead of passing commands & traffic over the network made the tests unacceptably slow. If you need to test a wide variety of browsers then the overhead diminishes because you can run in parallel...

Option 2, using a virtual display, is the simplest to configure on most servers. If you're using Linux the X Virtual Frame Buffer (XVFB) will get you up and running quickly. It's worth reading up on what's going on but the short answer is:

- Install XVFB (`sudo apt-get install xvfb`)
- Install Firefox (`sudo apt-get install firefox`)
- Start XVFB (`sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8 &`). You may want to add an init script so this happens every time the server starts
- In your CI server add `export DISPLAY=:10` as a step before the tests are run
- Run your tests

The XVFB creates a virtual display on `:10`, which you then set as the default display. When you start Firefox it's completely unaware that it's on a virtual display, so things like getting Geb to take screenshots of failing tests will work as normal.

For more information about the steps see:

- http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/
- https://github.com/tomaslin/grails-test-recipes
- http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html
- http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xvfb-run.1.html

If you need an init script to get it to start/stop, then there are quite a few to choose from, such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/jterrace/2911875).